# How can I uppercase each element of an array?

Tags: ruby, arrays

How can I turn an array of elements into uppercase? Expected output would be:

```
["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday"]  
=> ["MONDAY", "TUESDAY", "WEDNESDAY", "THURSDAY", "FRIDAY"]
```

The following didn't work and left them as lower case.

```
Day.weekday.map(&:name).each {|the_day| the_day.upcase }
 => ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday"]
```

Answer (score 68, accepted):

#### Return a New Array

If you want to return an uppercased array, use **#map**:

```
array = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday"]

# Return the uppercased version.
array.map(&:upcase)
=> ["MONDAY", "TUESDAY", "WEDNESDAY", "THURSDAY", "FRIDAY"]

# Return the original, unmodified array.
array
=> ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday"]
```

As you can see, the original array is not modified, but you can use the uppercased return value from #map anywhere you can use an expression.

#### Update Array in Place

If you want to uppercase the array in-place, use **#map!** instead:

```
array = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday"]
array.map!(&:upcase)
array
=> ["MONDAY", "TUESDAY", "WEDNESDAY", "THURSDAY", "FRIDAY"]
```

Comment: If an element in the array is nil, using array.map!(&:upcase) gives a no method error on it. How would I get around this? Thanks

Comment: @DanRio First use `.compact` to remove all `nil`s, then do `upcase`.. `array.compact!.map!(&:upcase)`

Answer (score 7):

This should work:

```
Day.weekday.map(&:name).map(&:upcase)
```

Or, if you want to save some CPU cycles

```
Day.weekday.map{|wd| wd.name.upcase}
```

Answer (score 4):

In your example, replace 'each' with 'map'.

While 'each' iterates through your array, it doesn't create a new array containing the values returned by the block.