# How to represent a serie of tickers' names in ruby along with R

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, r, series

I am trying to run a series of stock tickers in ruby through rails to do some calculation using R. But when I run the following module, I got the error saying that Rserve::Connection::EvalError: eval failed: Packet[cmd=50397186,len=, con='', status=error:'Parse error'(3)].

```
  def self.risk_return_plot(stock_ticker = ["VZ", "CHU", "T", "VOD", "DTEGY"])
       include_r_libraries
       stock_ticker = stock_ticker.map(&:capitalize)
       RSERVE.eval <<EOF
       myenv <- new.env()
       getSymbols("#{stock_ticker}", env = myenv)
       monthly.Return <- do.call(merge, c(eapply(myenv, monthlyReturn), all=FALSE))
       names(monthly.Return)[1:ncol(monthly.Return)] <- paste("#{stock_ticker}",    1:ncol(monthly.Return), sep="")
       names(monthly.Return) <- gsub("[[:digit:]]", "", names(monthly.Return) )
       tickers.return <- colMeans(monthly.Return)
       EOF
   end
```

reload!;a = DataVisual::risk_return_plot(stock_ticker = ["VZ", "CHU", "T", "VOD", "DTEGY"])

Comment: Where's your closing EOF?

Comment: You need to do `"#{@stock_ticker}"`. Note the double quotes. Ruby does not replace variables inside `#{}` with their values when using single quotes. Full line: `getSymbols("#{@stock_ticker}", env = myenv)`

Comment: I added the EOF and changed the code as you wrote, but it didn't work although.

Comment: I got the below error: NoMethodError: undefined method `upcase' for ["VZ", "CHU", "T", "VOD", "DTEGY"]:Array.

Comment: You are trying to call the upcase method (from the String class) on an Array. Try stock_ticker.map(&:upcase) - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11402362/how-can-i-uppercase-each-element-of-an-array

Comment: Thanks, I updated my code above but it says that Rserve::Connection::EvalError: eval failed: Packet[cmd=50397186,len=<nil>, con='<nil>', status=error:'Parse error'(3)]

Comment: @Max I just updated the question. Can you give me a hand with that?

Comment: Sorry I can't help you any more. I just saw a syntax error. I don't know R at all.