# How can one avoid a NoMethodError exception when mapping over nils in an array of strings?

Tags: arrays, ruby, string, exception, null

### The Question

In response to a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11402608/1301972), @DanRio asked this [follow-up question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11402362/how-can-i-uppercase-each-element-of-an-array/11402608#comment79334856_11402608):

> If an element in the array is nil, using array.map!(&:upcase) gives a no method error on it. How would I get around this?

Because this is outside the scope of the original question, I'm posting it here on his behalf.

### The Code

This is the snippet of code the user is asking about:

```
array = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday"]
array.map!(&:upcase)
```

Comment: If you want to target `nil` values specifically then a ternary with `nil?` would work: `array.map { |s| s.nil? ? s : s.upcase }`.

Comment: @sagarpandya82 There's nothing wrong with the ternary solution; it's perfectly valid Ruby from a conceptual standpoint. However, it's less compact and forces you to treat nils explicitly as a separate case. Unless it's significantly faster than the other options (see the [benchmarking answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46186858/1301972) below) then I'm not sure I see the advantage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The Problem

In the original question, the values in the array were all String objects. However, if the contents of the array aren't known ahead of time, then of course it's possible that some of the elements may be nil. Since nil doesn't [#respond_to?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Object.html#method-i-respond_to-3F) :upcase, any nils in the array will trigger the NoMethodError exception you're seeing.

### Potential Solutions

There are a number of ways to handle this, including:

1. Use [Array#compact](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#method-i-compact) to remove nils before mapping.
2. Explicitly handle the exception with [rescue](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/doc/syntax/exceptions_rdoc.html).
3. Use the block form of [Array#map!](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#method-i-map-21) to invoke the method using Ruby's new (as of Ruby 2.3.0) [safe navigation operator](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/11537).

I'll focus on the last item in the remainder of the answer.

### Use Ruby's Safe Navigation Operator

Which answer is best depends on context, but I recommend the safe navigation operator for the common case. I can't find it documented anywhere except the release notes, but it works a lot like the [Object#try](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-try) method from Rails.

Instead of mapping each element directly with `map! &:upcase` you would use safe navigation to only invoke [#upcase](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/String.html#method-i-upcase) on objects that respond to it. For example:

```
array = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", nil, "Friday"]
array.map! { |e| e&.upcase }
#=> ["MONDAY", "TUESDAY", "WEDNESDAY", "THURSDAY", nil, "FRIDAY"]
```

Comment: This is excellent thanks! I appreciate your response and posting of the question very much! Perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a benchmark for different approaches:

```
require 'benchmark'

arr = 100_000.times.map { nil }
Benchmark.bm do |bm|
  bm.report("compact then upcase\n") do
    arr.compact.each &:upcase
  end
  bm.report("save nagivation then upcase\n") do
    arr.each { |y| y&.upcase }
  end
  bm.report("respond_to then upcase\n") do
    arr.each { |y| y.upcase if y.respond_to?(:upcase) }
  end
  bm.report("boolean check then upcase\n") do
    arr.each { |y| y && y.upcase }
  end
end
```

and the results:

```
       user     system      total        real
compact then upcase
  0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000912)
save nagivation then upcase
  0.020000   0.000000   0.020000 (  0.005030)
respond_to then upcase
  0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.009824)
boolean check then upcase
  0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.005254)
```

You can see that compact is the fastest, but there's an important difference between its results and the others. It does *not* include any nil values in the result, and if some items were skipped then the result will be a different length.

So I would say if you want the result to not preserve the `nil`, then use compact, otherwise use the boolean or safe navigation, which perform about the same.